# Laravel Queue doesnt run as background

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

hi i created a laravel queue job to send mails

```
public function handle() {
    foreach($this->emails as $value) {
            $to         = $value->email;
            $subject    = $this->data['subject'];       
            $this->data['t_firstname']    = $value->firstname;
            $this->data['t_lastname']     = $value->lastname;
            if (view()->exists('mail.requirement_to_tutor')) {
                    $view = view('mail.requirement_to_tutor',$this->data);
                    $html = $view->render();
            }
            file_put_contents('test.txt', 'test database');
            $body = $html;
            $headers  = "From: " . $this->data['from'] . "\r\nReply-To: " . $this->data['from'] . "";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }
}
```

and also i am pushing datas from repo

```
$obj = (new SendStudentRequirement($TutorsbyCity,$data));
$this->dispatch($obj);
```

but it doesnot run as background , the function is waiting untill the queue finish , help me out please

Comment: did you change the queue driver to something other than 'sync' ?

Comment: i followed  1.php artisan queue:table  2.php artisan make:job SendStudentRequirement --queued thats it , i didnt touched queue driver and all

Comment: did you try Mail::queue instead of mail() ?

Comment: Mail queue needs some third party mail sending so i used normal mail

Comment: do you have any queue listeners running ?

Comment: If you changed `QUEUE_DRIVER` to `database`, have you run `php artisan config:cache` to create new cached config file ?

Comment: i am using database queue and it created a row for each process with attempts = 0, reserved = o, i am looking forward for how to work with queue listener , i am new to laravel thats why lot of confusion , now i think i am almost 90 % to accomplish the task

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek  yes run that artisan command to clear cache.

Comment: Have you changed this config (and cache again) before or after running queue listener? If before, you should stop the listener and start it again to make sure it's using latest config.

Comment: everything works fine , and may i know how to automatically process the queue listener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the **sync** driver is used. You should change this to another driver that is listed in `config/queue.php`

Look for the following line in your `.env` file and adjust to a different driver:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

[Laravel - Docs - Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues)

Comment: QUEUE_DRIVER=database i changed to this , eventhough the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using a default configuration of `"sync"`, that means that all queue jobs will run synchronously instead of "fire and forget" way. To change this default behavior you can follow these steps:

### 1. Select a diferent Queue Connection

Open the *.env* configuration file and add **QUEUE_DRIVER** parameter with one of the supported values: "database", "beanstalkd", "sqs" or "redis". In this case we are going to use a **database connection** as an example mode: `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`

### 2. Edit connection driver

Open the */config/queue.php* file and configure your driver connection, for example:

```
'database' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90
        ]
```

Then run the next commands to create the new `jobs` table:

```
php artisan config:cache && php artisan queue:table
```

So, you already have the queue as "fire and forget" way; you can try and see how the `jobs` table was created with the information of the queue.

### 3. Configure a process manager for a long-running

To execute the pending queues in the future we can use a process manager as [supervisor](http://supervisord.org). You can install supervisor for Ubuntu and Debian running the following command: `sudo apt-get install supervisor`

Then open the supervisor file: `sudo nano /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` and add a line like the following to the end of the file:

```
[program:laravel-worker-QUEUE_NAME]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command= php /var/www/MY_PROJECT/artisan queue:work --queue=QUEUE_NAME --sleep=15
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/MY_PROJECT/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Replace the values of: `QUEUE_NAME` and `MY_PROJECT`. Note that the `--sleep` parameter is the time (seconds) to verify for new queues in the database. You can see more details of the configuration file in the [official documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html).

Finally execute these commands to enable the program:

`sudo supervisorctl reread && sudo supervisorctl update`

You can check the status of the queues in the configured log file: */var/www/MY_PROJECT/storage/logs/worker.log*

Comment: @codiiv, Was a jobs table automatically created with the information of the queue? (Step 2)

Answer (score 0):

use this laravel queue function :- dispatchAfterResponse

for eg : $obj = (new SendStudentRequirement($TutorsbyCity,$data));
$this->dispatchAfterResponse($obj);