# How to manually run a laravel/lumen job using command line

Tags: php, laravel, shell, laravel-5, lumen

I have created a Job file in the folder `app/Jobs/MyJob.php` and i would like to run it just once, if its possible using command line.

Something like:

`> php MyJob:run`

what command should I use to run a method in this file or the handle?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I created [mxl/laravel-job](https://github.com/mxl/laravel-job) composer package providing Laravel command for dispatching jobs from command line:

```
$ composer require mxl/laravel-job
$ php artisan job:dispatch YourJob # for jobs in app/Jobs directory (App\Jobs namespace)
$ php artisan job:dispatch '\Path\To\YourJob' # dispatch job by its full class name
$ php artisan job:dispatchNow YourJob # dispatch immediately
$ php artisan job:dispatch YourJob John 1990-01-01 # dispatch with parameters
```

Package also provides a way to reduce boilerplate by using base `Job` class and has `FromParameters` interface that allows to implement command line parameters parsing and use job from PHP code and command line simultaneously.

Read more about its features at [the package GitHub page](https://github.com/mxl/laravel-job).

**OLD ANSWER**

Run

```
php artisan make:command DispatchJob
```

to create special artisan command that runs jobs.

Open created `DispatchJob.php` file and define `DispatchJob` class like this:

```
class DispatchJob extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'job:dispatch {job}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Dispatch job';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $class = '\\App\\Jobs\\' . $this->argument('job');
        dispatch(new $class());
    }
}
```

Now you should start queue worker:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

and after that you can run jobs from command line:

```
php artisan job:dispatch YourJobNameHere
```

Comment: Awesome, but I got  *- mongodb/mongodb 1.5.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.*

Comment: @LeoGasparrini My package uses only `"laravel/framework": "^5.5"` dependency. It's more likely an issue with your project dependencies.

Comment: hi, could you release the version that supported laravel 10?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur could you prepare PR please? I will review and approve it.

Answer (score 19):

The most simple way is to call with the use of Tinker

It's Laravel command using for debugging, use it by running below command from from project root

```
php artisan tinker
```

To dispatch job on a specific queue from tinker

> `\Queue::pushON('rms', new App\Jobs\UpdateRMS());`
>
> first parameter - Queue name
>
> second parameter - job name

Dispatch multiple jobs at once to a specific queue

```
\Queue::bulk([new App\Jobs\UpdateRMS(), new App\Jobs\UpdateRMS()], null, 'rms');
```

**Demo** (product-service is my project name) Just follow it
[image]
**Find a dispatched job in the queue)** my case queue is configured as Redis

[image]

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer - it does not contain any information how this should be run using CLI

Comment: Hey Nico, I've added more details, hope that helps.

Comment: with Tinker it's also possible to simply run helper `dispatch_now(new MyJob(new MyArgs()))`

Comment: Yeah this method is clean !

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a `QUEUE_DRIVER` diferent to **sync** and you want to dispatch a queue that you have created before, from your project folder run the command:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=MyQueueName
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523550/laravel-queue-doesnt-run-as-background/51676319#51676319) to configure a **database** `QUEUE_DRIVER`

Comment: Realised I was creating different queues, adding thhe chunk `--queue=QueueName` is very key

Answer (score 2):

> for Job With Parameter Optional

try this one

```
class DispatchJob extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'job:dispatch {job} {parameter?}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Dispatch job';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $prefix = '\\App\Jobs\\';

        $jobClassName = trim($this->argument('job'));
        if(stripos($jobClassName,"/")){
            $jobClassName = str_replace('/','\\',$jobClassName);
        }
        $class = '\\App\\Jobs\\' . $jobClassName;

        if(!class_exists($class)){
            $this->error("{$class} class Not exists");
        }else {
            if ($this->argument('parameter')) {
                $job = new $class($this->argument('parameter'));
            } else {
                $job = new $class();
            }

            dispatch($job);
            $this->info("Successfully Dispatch {$class} ");
        }

    }
}
```

now U can try like this in terminal

1.Without Folder

```
php artisan job:dispatch appJob
```

2.With Folder

```
php artisan job:dispatch folderName/appJob
```

3.Folder With Parameter

```
php artisan job:dispatch folderName/appJob 12
```