# Cron job isn't working in Cpanel - Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel, laravel-9

I want to write a schedule in Laravel 9 which requests to an API and saves the results in the database.

Then I should add a cron job in my Cpanel to run it every minute.

My Laravel code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\CurrenciesChart;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CurrenciesInfo extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'currency:info';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Getting currencies data';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\CurrenciesInfo;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        CurrenciesInfo::class,
    ];
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('currency:info')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan schedule:work` locally, it works just fine but it doesn't seem to work on the host.

I've tried many queries such as below but nothing happened and there isn't any error in `laravel.log`.

I set the schedule to every minute (* * * * *) and tried the following queries.

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/univardi/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

`cd /home/univardi/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

`cd /home/univardi/public_html && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

`/usr/local/bin/ea-php81 /home/univardi/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

But none of them worked.

Comment: As a side note you *might* gain some insight into command line Laravel [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357472/how-to-manually-run-a-laravel-lumen-job-using-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to `touch /tmp/test.txt`. After one minute checks the /tmp/test.txt file that exists or not. If the file exists you realize that the cron job works normally, Then change the original query to:

```
cd /home/univardi/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/job.log 2>&1
```

check `/tmp/job.log` file to find out the error of the query(it can be not found error), Then fix the problem and at the end replace `/tmp/job.log` with `/dev/null`